# How do you answer this question?

Tags: interviewing, manager

I was asked this question in an Interview. The position that I am interviewing for is middle management in a large company. I've interviewed for this position several times and they always ask the same (or very similar) questions.

I am not sure how to answer this

> Please project or forecast at least five different ways that the job
>   you are applying for will likely change and evolve over the next three
>   years as a result of business changes, technology changes, and a
>   faster, more innovative environment and explain how your role will be
>   critical throughout this evolution.

The position is for a Junior IT Manager at very large international company.

The truth is that I can't see into the future and figure out what upper management is planning. They usually leave me out of these meetings.

Yet on every Interview, they ask this "standard" question.

Comment: yea i agree with you but i dont think they want to hear that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they want you to show that you're thinking about what the role of the job entails. So. They're wanting someone who has thought about what the business landscape might look like over the next few years, the possible impacts of technology on operations, and how you might exploit this to create a competitive advantage.

I don't know what you're interviewing for, but let's say your going for a hotel management job.

One way might be the disruption in the labour force due to mechanisation - say impacting the staff that deliver food up to rooms. You might want to suggest using a small delivery robot to see if this could be a viable cost savings (and maybe even marketing - get your food delivered by a robot!) measure.

Then you might look at the impact of airbnb, booking.com on the hotel industry - should the hotel be opening up rooms on airbnb, creating a competitive advantage by offering the rooms as either standard serviced or not?

Are there any software products that might make managing a hotel more efficient - are there ways that large parties can be planned in a simpler manner, could the hotel use this to

Look, you get the idea. You need to think about the industry (read a business paper or two, daily) and then the company (read the annual report, your CEOs will have a company vision outlined there, replaying that back to them shows you've read the annual report, which will put you in front of some people).

Why not ask a senior manager to lunch/coffee and talk to them about some aspect of the changes that you read about, how some interest - this will put you ahead too.